# Directly accessing matrix values within a for-loop

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix containing:

```
n =
49898
148954
224156
224602
167493
100970
50645
21352
8168
2659
806
227
55
12
3
```

How can I use the numbers held within 'n' to specify the number of iterations a for-loop should contain? i.e. I want the loop to do 49898 iterations before moving on to do 148954 and so forth. I have other nested for-loops which also need to advance by '1' once 49889 or 148954 etc. complete thus I can not just SUM 'n'. 
I know only of:

`for i=n` and for `i=1:n` styles of for-loop, neither of which solves this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a nested `for`-loop:

```
for i=1:length(n)
    for j=1:n(i)
        % do something
    end
end
```

Comment: It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)